# Gauss Bell Curve - Non negative numbers - Will curve shape from trigonometry be the same as from empirical data?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Im Johan, new to physics stack exchange, second post. How are you doing:)

Would you help me with this Gauss Bell Curve question please?

Im just looking for a general way to skew the normal distribution curve when its only positive values. Posting it in physics, not math, because you guys do actual measurments and not just theory i suppose.

The practical application is to fit data (x-values that is and can only be positive values) with the right shape normal distribution to make a best guess.

(A couple of years ago i studied engineering, almost finished, got sick in bipolar disorder.

In school we studied some statistics and physics.)

From what i remember Gauss Bell Curve is cos(x + X) 
Delta x = pi
where X is expected maximum y- value and trig function is stretched out on infinite negative to infinite positive x-axis. The trig function never reaches the perimeter. (?)

In other words that trig function and normal distribution is the same thing?

Ive only got cell phone so i drew what i meen on paper and attached image to this post.

Thx for taking a look at it, merry christams:)

[image: Gauss Bell Curve and trigonometry]

[image: Gauss Bell Curve and trigonometry2]

Some details

Cosinus on bell curve axis (bigger and bigger spacing between angles)
[image]

Bell curve lower bound (on ordinary axis not bigger and bigger spacing between angles) and cosinus is upper bound
[image]

Bell curve upper equation and cos lower equation
[image]

Window settings
[image]

Comment: This question is not about physics. Also, are you aware that there is a mathematical formula for the bell curve?

Comment: Ok, my bad, sorry. Thought it was physics like those radiation from radioactive stuff and you got a geiger thingy? I just wanted to know how well the math correlates with actual mesaurments? I wasnt aware that there were a general formula thats always true, thx for letting me kbow. Im rookie

Comment: I meen in regard to wavelengths as an example, they cant be negative if i remember right

Comment: Hi Johan, welcome to Physics SE. Unfortunately this question will be closed unless you give us some more details, including some context of the problem, e.g. do you want to fit data to a Bell-curve? Or to a sin curve? Can you pick one?

Comment: Hi Cavarec:) thank you for welcomeing me and showing me the ropes, appreciate it. Just woke up. Will elaborate later today if thats ok? Im not that good at reading lengths of text, got adhd so a short text seems pretty long, therefore i dont know if i should edit the question or write more details in comments? Thx for your time

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: A tale from the 20th century: once there was a time when someone wondering about the time could ask someone who had a time machine, this machine was called a watch, what time it was. In todays society you must check all options before asking, just watch

Comment: Sorry for sassy answer, had a ad day i guess. Happy new year:)